# Laravel redirect function does not work in another class function

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make registration and login system. Registiration and login controller is at different files as classs. When I register a user in registration class and call login function from loginController, redirect()->to("checkLogin") does not work. But if I do same thing at registrationController, it works.

Here the registerController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
//use App\Https\loginController;
use Auth;
class registrationController extends Controller

{
   /* private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $foldername;
*/
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        /*-----------------------------------------*/
        /*Kullanıcı verilerinin veritabanına kayıt edilmesi için request fonksiyonu ile değişkenlere atanır.*/ 
        $username = request()->input('username');
        $password = Hash::make(request()->input('password'));
        $email = request()->input('email');
        /*-----------------------------------------*/
        
        /*-----------------------------------------*/
        /*Kullanıcı adına oluşturulan klasörün ismini rastgele seçmek için kullanıcı adı ve email adresi bir hash algoritmasından geçirilir.*/
        $foldername = hash('sha256',$username.$email);
        /*-----------------------------------------*/
        
        /*-----------------------------------------*/
        /*Kullanıcı bilgilerinin veritabanında saklanması için bir SQL sorgusu yapılır.*/
        DB::table('users')->insert(
            ['email' => $email, 'username' => $username, 'password'=>$password,'foldername'=>$foldername]
        );

        /*-----------------------------------------*/
        $credentials = request()->only('email', 'password');
        //return redirect()->to("checkLogin");
        loginController::login($credentials);

       
    
      
        
    }

    
}
```

Here the loginController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Auth;

class loginController extends Controller{

    public static function login($credentials){

        echo 'test1';
        
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        
            echo 'test2';
            return redirect()->to('checkLogin');
            echo 'test3';
            /*intended('checkLogin')
                        ->withSuccess('Logged-in');*/
        }
        else{
            echo 'yanlış şifre veya email';
            
        } 
    }


}

?>
```

all comments for just me.

Thanks for everything...

Comment: Have you tried removing all the `echo`s first, so that there's no output before redirecting?

Comment: In your register controller you need to add a `return` before `loginController::login($credentials);`

Comment: @SaineshMamgain I got what you mean so many thanks. I confuesed as I used reutrn at login class. If I don't want to use return at registitarionController, what should I do ?

Comment: @brombeer Thanks for your comments, there were output before redirecting. Also Sainesh Mamgain solved my problem.

Comment: @Wtow you cannot redirect in Laravel without using `return`. You can use native php method `header()` but it doesn't makes any sense as any code after redirection will not execute.